# How to discard uncommitted local changes in git? (reset, checkout, clean not working)

Tags: git

I have some local modifications, as shown by `git status`:

```
git status
# On branch foobar-stage
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/images/android-alert-lightgray.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/images/search-white.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/android-share-alt.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/backup-menu.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/custom-email.svg
```

I expect them to be discarded by `git reset --hard`, but immediately after doing this, `git status` still shows the same modified files. So then I try `git clean -f` which has no output, but still `git status` shows the same files.

The output of `git checkout` is

```
git checkout
M   themes/foobar/svg/images/android-alert-lightgray.svg
M   themes/foobar/svg/images/search-white.svg
M   themes/foobar/svg/source/android-share-alt.svg
M   themes/foobar/svg/source/backup-menu.svg
M   themes/foobar/svg/source/custom-email.svg
```

But after doing this, `git status` still shows the same files.

I've checked and re-checked file permissions. In fact, I'm able to `rm` those files myself:

```
rm themes/foobar/svg/images/android-alert-lightgray.svg
rm themes/foobar/svg/images/search-white.svg
```

Afterward, `git status` shows:

```
git status
# On branch foobar-stage
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    themes/foobar/svg/images/android-alert-lightgray.svg
#   deleted:    themes/foobar/svg/images/search-white.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/android-share-alt.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/backup-menu.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/custom-email.svg
```

Then, if I `git reset --hard` again, it restores those deleted files, to their modified state.

Checking `git status` again gives:

```
git status
# On branch foobar-stage
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/images/android-alert-lightgray.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/images/search-white.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/android-share-alt.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/backup-menu.svg
#   modified:   themes/foobar/svg/source/custom-email.svg
```

#### Edit:

A little bit more information:

This is a really annoying git-ism, that I don't have a firm grasp on. Once files are committed using one file format, and then you change .gitattributes, you end up in the situation where directly after a checkout, git shows the files as modified. You can't reset (they just end up showing as modified again), or checkout a different branch, because git says you must commit or stash. I spent some time today trying to recreate the symptom in a sandbox, but who has time for that! As far as I know there is no graceful way to recover; on one machine, you backup and delete all the affected files (and commit). Then add them to the repo again, commit and push. Then, everyone else who has that repo checked out will have to trash their whole directory, and re-clone. Because they won't be able to checkout a different branch (error message about commit or stash), and they won't be able to pull (error message about commit or stash). If someone knows a graceful way to remedy the above, please share.

Comment: What does `git diff` says? It can help to know why git is considering the files as modified.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` file with those SVG files listed in it?

Comment: BTW, `git checkout` without any arguments is a no-op. In order to drop the changes in the working directory you must run `git checkout -- .` (if you want to make the working directory a copy of the index) or `git checkout HEAD -- .` (note the . argument which stands for *current directory*).

Comment: @Leon I believe you're onto something, because a fresh clone on a different computer shows the same set of files 'modified' immediately after checkout. I'm still working on this, and I'll post an answer soon, unless you or someone else posts the answer first. I've got to brush up on exactly how .gitattributes works, and why git would see these files supposedly modified (by itself) immediately after checkout.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey Before self-answering the question, you better first correct the question.

Comment: I think the question is right. The answer is something like "Notice that checkout immediately results in modified files. This means git itself is modifying the files. If you git diff one of the files, you'll see that it has only changed line endings." ... The part of the answer that's not known yet, is the exact procedure to (a) figure out what changes need to be made in .gitattributes, and (b) commit those changes in such a way that others can pull without resulting in conflict.

Comment: What is your OS? I had similar issues on Windows with `core.filemode=true` several years ago. If you are on Windows and have `core.filemode=true` try doing `git config --local core.filemode false`.

Comment: My guess is case folding. Can you verify with `git ls-files` that the case and presence (or lack thereof) of spaces in names are consistent with what you see on disk? Also make sure you don't have two files with the same name only casing differences, such as having both `Readme` and `README` as an example.